# Selected menu from html dropdown turns blank for some options

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am building a simple html page where there is a drop down. I am getting an unusual error. There is around 9-10 options in one of my drop down. While selecting any option from 7-8 options it gets updated in the text field. But when I select any option from renaming 3 options as soon as cursor loose focus from the drop down, the field turns blank. Below is my code of drop down:

```
<td width="500px"><select name="car_name" id="car_nam"
    class="css-input">
        <option value="White Dzire">Dzire</option>
        <option value="White Swift Dzire">Swift Dzire</option>
        <option value="White Amaze">Amaze</option>
        <option value="White WagonR">WagonR</option>
        <option value="White Ritz">Ritz</option>
        <option value="White i10">i10</option>
        <option value="Grey Beat">Beat</option>
        <option value="White Indica">Indica</option>
        <option value="Bajaj-RE">Auto-Bajaj-RE</option>
        <option value="White Xylo">Xylo</option>
        <option value="White Ertiga">Ertiga</option>
        <option value="White Innova">Innova</option>
        <option value="White Accord">Accord</option>
        <option value="White Etios">Etios</option>
        <option value="White Nissan Micra">Micra</option>
        <option value="White Verito">Verito</option>
        <option value="White Altis">Altis</option>
        <option value="White Skoda Rapid">Rapid</option>

</select></td>
```

When I select any option other than WagonR, i10 or Auto-bajaj-re, it works as expected. But when I select any option from above listed car, the drop down turns blank.

Comment: Can you update codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: i check it work properly.......

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```